# Why can I not add points in CGAL

Tags: c++, geometry, operator-overloading, point, cgal

I am trying to add two points in CGAL using the `+` operator.

```
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Point_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point;

using namespace std;

cout << Point(8.9, 9) + Point(1,1) << endl;
cout << Point(8.9, 9) + Point(2,2) * .5 << endl;
```

Which I assume to be possible considering the [documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Point__2.html#ga7be1ffd6b3e12cbe03575d932420c672).

But I get the following error:

```
/path_to_file/main.cpp:25: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘Point {aka CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> >}’ and ‘Point {aka CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> >}’)
 cout << Point(8.9, 9) + Point(1,1) << endl;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You need to put your `std::cout`statements inside a function. maybe `int main()`?

Comment: It is not mathematically correct. With `Vector_2` is it valid.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing it, but where in the documentation does it say that you can add two points? Mathematically, this shouldn’t be allowed.

Comment: "It is not mathematically correct." How so? Adding points is completely reasonable mathematically and common place in any math book or lecture. For example, the midpoint of two points A and B is C = (A+B)/2. I don't need to artificially introduce the origin just to make everything vectors C = O + (A-O)/2 + (B-O)/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was misreading the documentation. You can only add vectors to points. (Which makes totally sense, of course)

From the documentation :

> Point_2< Kernel > operator+ (const Point_2< Kernel > &p, const Vector_2< Kernel > &v) returns the point obtained by translating p by the vector v